# You had better, are better, better, It's better?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

What are the differences between these four sorts of constructs in a sentence, please?

*You are better ...

you had better ...

You better ...

It's better [that] you ....*

Comment: You had done better to include complete sentences.

Comment: I liked to make it an option for the responder.

Comment: This is far too broad. Besides which not all native speakers will agree on "acceptable" usages in this area. Personally, I don't find @Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment syntactically acceptable, upvotes notwithstanding.

Comment: As @Tᴚoɯɐuo suggests, you are better off providing [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), as opposed to options, as is discussed at length in [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: FumbleFingers: It's seen its heyday, true, but it's not without contemporary attestations. (ignore the non-attestations) https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had+done+better+to%22&num=20&lr=lang_en&newwindow=1&tbs=lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXudWn19DYAhXLS98KHZN4BtQQpwUIIA&biw=1211&bih=944&dpr=0.9

Comment: Actually, I think this is a valid learner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You are better*: A comparison phrase -- You are better at golf than I am.

*You had better*: This is a colloquial phrase meaning "you should" or "you must" or "I demand that you" (do something).

*You better*: Same as above, with a little less colloquial flavor. Used in common phrases like "You better believe it!" and "You better not!" (Don't do that!)

*It's better [that] you*: A more standard way of suggesting or demanding that you do something. A more perfect wording would be conditional: "It would be better if you (did this thing that I want)."

Comment: You better believe it is: you (had) better believe it. It's shortened in colloquial form.

Comment: It's better that you ... isn't really a *demand* but I agree that it's a suggestion.

Comment: One of the reasons I called it colloquial in the long form too is because I can't find a grammatical reason for using "had" when it's not a past perfect tense -- it's kind of a verbal pun almost -- you're referring to a future action and using a (form of) past tense.

Comment: It is a form of *irrealis*, broadly construed, an urging or admonition, not a declaration of something you actually did.